# How to explicitly start transaction in Java Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring-transactions

I'm using ProxySQL, and set up some 'Read/Write split rules'. Whether I use `TransactionTemplate` or the `@Transactional` annotation to start a transaction, it implicitly starts the transaction.

Is there any way to start transaction explicitly? just like this:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
BEGIN
// SQL queries
COMMIT
```

Can I use AOP to solve this problem?

I tried this:

```
transactionTemplate.execute(transactionStatus -> {
            jdbcTemplate.execute("BEGIN");
            // The first SQL query there is SELECT
            ...
            // UPDATE SQL 
            return transactionStatus;
});
```

And all queries were distributed on primary MySQL node.

If I remove `jdbcTemplate.execute("BEGIN");`, The first SELECT query was distributed on slave MySQL node by 'Read/Write split rules'. Now I can't change my 'Read/Write split rules', Can I use AOP to intercept Spring transactions and explicitly start transactions, while still using TransactionTemplate or @Transactional annotation?

Comment: Before reinventing the wheel, what's wrong with using `@Transactional`?